# MySQL syntax error when attempting to POST data using express and postman

Tags: mysql, database, express, postman

Im attempting to post some test data into a MYsql database with the following query:

```
Asset.create = (newAsset, result) => {
    sql.query("INSERT INTO `assets` VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", newAsset, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error", err);
            result(err, null);
            return;
        }

        console.log("Created new asset : ", { id: res.insertId, ...newAsset});
        result(null, {id: res.insertId, ...newAsset});
    });
```

using the following Json input in postman:

```
{
    "Id" : 6,
    "AccountID" : "6",
    "AssetID" : "6",
    "AssetSymbol" : "6",
    "Amount" : "60"

}
```

However I get the following error:

```
 sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1",
  sql: "INSERT INTO `assets` VALUES (`id` = 6, `accountid` = '6', `assetid` = '6', `assetsymbol` = '6', `amount` = '60', ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

The MySQL model for my assets table is as follows:

```
Id: INT (Not autoincrementing)
AccountID: VARCHAR(45)
AssetID: VARCHAR(45)
AssetSymbol: VARCHAR(45)
Amount: VARCHAR(45)
```

I know its a terrible design for a MySQL database. Its only a test database for now until I get the hang of using MySql with express and will make a new proper one later.
Any advice on what Im doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you are confusing/mixing at least 3 different methods of writing an INSERT. There is  [Documentation about MySQL and the INSERT specifically](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) Maybe you shoud give it a quick review

Comment: I think you may be able to do it like this, judging by what it gets expanded to `sql.query("INSERT INTO \`assets\` SET ?, ?, ?, ?, ?", newAsset .....`

Comment: ALternatively using what you have pass just the values in the parameter `[6,6,6,60]`

Comment: I did suspect I was getting different methods mixed up. I had one method that didnt work so I hopped onto Stack to find other methods of inserting to mysql. It didnt fit my other work perfectly so I made it fit as best I could

Comment: Nonetheless someone below found a way to make it work. Thanks for all your suggestions friends. Its appreciated

Comment: Yes, doing what I suggested in one of my comments hours ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal `node-mysql` library doesn't support using an object like this. You should convert the object into an array:

```
Asset.create = (newAsset, result) => {
  sql.query("INSERT INTO `assets` VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Object.values(newAsset), (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    console.log("Created new asset : ", {
      id: res.insertId,
      ...newAsset
    });
    result(null, {
      id: res.insertId,
      ...newAsset
    });
  });
}
```

There are a number of packages that add named placeholders, you can find them with Google. Then you would be able to write:

```
Asset.create = (newAsset, result) => {
  sql.query("INSERT INTO `assets` VALUES (:Id, :AccountID, :AssetID, :AssetSymbol, :Amount)", newAsset, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    console.log("Created new asset : ", {
      id: res.insertId,
      ...newAsset
    });
    result(null, {
      id: res.insertId,
      ...newAsset
    });
  });
}
```